# Want to use doubly circular linked list in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Actually, I have been trying to read binary files data and after it reached last line(last node). I am not able to navigate the last node to the first to start the whole cycle again. So I want to use circular doubly linked list in VBA. How can i use that?
thanks

```
Private Sub Next_btn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Next_btn.Click


    If (TextBox_PartNumber.Text.Length = 0) Then

        ErrorHandling(TextBox_PartNumber, TextBox_Description)
    Else

        Dim nextloadData As New OrderData
        **nextloadData.PartNumber = br.ReadString**  "after it read all lines in the binary file, it is showing error in this line like there is no data in the binary file. so i want to set the position of reading the files again at the begining of the files so how can i do that?"
        nextloadData.Description = br.ReadString
        nextloadData.Quantity = br.ReadInt32
        nextloadData.UnitPrice = br.ReadDouble

        'nodes = m_PartsData.First

        If nodes Is Nothing Then
            'm_PartsData.AddFirst(nextloadData)
            nodes = m_PartsData.First
        Else

            If Not nodes.Next Is Nothing Then
                m_PartsData.AddLast(nextloadData)
                nodes = nodes.Next
                TextBox_PartNumber.Text = nextloadData.PartNumber
                TextBox_Description.Text = nextloadData.Description
                TextBox_Quantity.Text = nextloadData.Quantity
                TextBox_UnitPrice.Text = nextloadData.UnitPrice
            Else
                m_PartsData.AddLast(nextloadData)
                TextBox_PartNumber.Text = nextloadData.PartNumber
                TextBox_Description.Text = nextloadData.Description
                TextBox_Quantity.Text = nextloadData.Quantity
                TextBox_UnitPrice.Text = nextloadData.UnitPrice

            End If

        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: VBA or vb.net?  And show us where your at

Comment: It just isn't clear here what you are trying to do or what the problem is.  Can you point to a line of code and say "*this line is supposed to do X, but instead it does Y(or does nothing or throws an error)*"?

Comment: Is it clear now? i have put the comment line which is having problem.